# keras fit_generator parameter steps_per_epoch

Tags: neural-network, keras, training-data

I want to use the keras model.fit_generator method for that I wrote my own generator and for the method I need to define the parameter "steps_per_epoch" I want to use every training data once for every epoch.

Now my problem is I generate the features in the generator I read wav-files and create the fft and before I start the training I don't know how much batches/samples I have. I can calculate the fft for every file before I start using the fit_generator method but every time I change my dataset(>20GB) I would need to recalculate the fft for every file and save the count for steps per epoch. Is there a better way how I can define that the fit_generator uses every sample only one time without calculate the steps per epoch? Or can my own generator pass the fit_generator when to start a new epoch?

Here is the code for my generator

```
def my_generator(filename_list):
    while True:
        for fname in filename_list:
                data, sr = librosa.load(fname)
                fft_result = librosa.core.stft(data)
                batches = features.create_batches(fft_result, batch_size)

                for i in range(len(batches)):
                    yield (batches[i], label)

model.fit_generator(my_generator(filename_list=filename_list, batch_size=batch_size), steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=10)
```

Comment: What is the problem with just counting the number of files when you instantiate your generator and passing that to Keras? Assuming you want to give all your data to train a network.

Comment: the problem is that every wav-file has different length that means one big wav-file maybe has 1000 fft-samples and other wav-files have only 200 fft-samples so I do not know the number of samples except if I calculate the fft for every file and count how many batches I need but this costs much time for big datasets

Comment: Is there any need to identify from which file each ftt sample comes? If a file has 700 batches, does it matter if you create 3 different batches with 300,300 and 100 samples? --- Or if two fales have 150 samples each, is it a problem to create only one batch with 300 samples for them?

Comment: I do not need to identify from which file each fft sample come but I have data>20GB and I do not know how many samples I've got and so I cannot tell the generator when he is finished with training every sample once and start new epoch. I could just yield one hugh batch for every file and tell the fit_generator "steps_per_epoch"=number_of_files but then it would learn on different sizes of batches which is I think not very nice

Comment: I have the same problem with my generator. Currently, I just guess the dataset size. Thus one epoch could see some batches twice (x)or not at all. Would that be a problem when training?
I would recommend that the batches have the same size. You could do that with another generator where you get $batch_size$ samples from each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

For each file in the list, you have to calculate fft that has 'n' batches where 'n' is different for each file. If this is the case than:

1. Navie method is to loop through the batch generator to calculate the actual number of batches. This process needs to be done only once. you can save that number for future use as well.
2. The second method could be to assign an arbitrary number to step_per_epoch. That arbitrary number should be greater than or equal to the number of files in the list multiplied by the number of the batches each fft can generate. The number of fft batches could be an arbitrary number. This way, if you shuffle data after the external "for" loop completes, then after some epoch statistically speaking all training data would be seen by the model. By using early_stop you can have properly converged model where "epochs" should be a very large value, 1000 for example.